# Is there possible to set color of a barplot in R in a range of colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am a beginner in R
I have a dataframe with 2 column contain the Title of each analysis as the first column and values between 6.7 to 14 as second column.
and I need to made a barplot like this one
[image]

my dataframe named FEA:

```
Tit   lp 
hsa05225 14.0  
hsa05165 12.0  
hsa05200 10.0  
hsa05163  9.2  
GO:0045785  8.8   
hsa04550  8.5   
GO:0022409  8.3   
hsa04218  8.3   
hsa05213  8.2   
hsa04115  7.8   
GO:0010720  7.6   
GO:0022407  7.2  
GO:1902532  6.9
```

I have used this code:

```
colnames(FEA)<-c("Tit","lp")
FEA$Row<-c(13:1)
    ggplot(FEA,aes(Row,lp,fill=Tit))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ coord_flip()+
      scale_x_discrete(name="") +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18),expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,15))+ 
labs(y= "-log10(P)") +theme(legend.title=element_blank())+ scale_color_discrete(name="")+ theme_bw()
```

But I need to show legend in front of each bar and change colors from red to yellow and also add the vertical lines in back of the bars if it is possible.

Comment: Yes it is.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  I'm not sure why your `fill=Tit` isn't wotking inside your `aes()`.  That's the correct approach, but I don't have your data.  You can add vertical black lines with `... + geom_vref(yintercept=c(...))`.

Comment: I add my data and more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

You can manually change the bar colors.

```r
library(readr) # for reading your sample data
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes) # for theme_few()

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Tit,lp), y=lp, fill=lp))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(2,4,6,10), color="lightgrey")+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width=.8) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#FFE06F", high = "#DD6602") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18),
                     expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,15))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(position="top", expand=c(0.08,0.08))+
  labs(y= "-log10(P)", x="") + 
  theme_few() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we could do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

colors <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))(length(unique(FEA$Tit)))

FEA %>% 
  mutate(Row = rev(row_number()),
         colors = colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))(length(unique(FEA$Tit)))
         ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Row,lp,fill=fct_inorder(Tit)))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_discrete(name="") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18),expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,15))+ 
  labs(y= "-log10(P)") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+ scale_color_discrete(name="")+ 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]